# Female version of "It's a wonderful life"

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a female lead version of the James Stewart film "It's a wonderful life"

Googling keeps bringing me to a late 1970s TV movie titled "It happened one Christmas" but that is **not** the one I'm looking for.

I saw this film much earlier in 1970 or 1971 and it was on my mother's b+w television.

Some updates:

- It may not have taken place at Christmas.
- I think the lady was a small town schoolteacher who got onto the town council, she was a major influence over the young minds for several decades.
- She was shown what the town would be like if she'd never existed.

NOTE:

It turns out this film was "Good Morning Miss Dove" from 1955.
I must have got it memory merged with "It happened one Christmas"
Apologies to all because there's no SFF connection
(I've voted to close!)

Comment: Clarence was a 1990 made-for-television film that featured a younger appearing version of the angel from It's a Wonderful Life - helping a (as I recall) a mom start up a software company.  Was on the Family Channel.  Commercials and VHS on youtube.  Wrong year obviously.

Comment: Generally in these situations your memory is what is likely faulty.  Are you sure it was the plot of It's a Wonderful Life - but with a female lead?  If you saw it in 1970 do you think it was made in 1970 too or some other decade?  Was it a film or a tv special?  How do you know it was NOT "It happened one Christmas" These sorts of questions may help others help you.  Good luck.

Comment: I would echo lucasbachmann. It looks like numerous versions of "It's a Wonderful Life" have hit television. Laverne and Shirley did a version in 1981, as an example. My guess is 1970/1971 timeframe is correct if you remember the TV set. But perhaps it could have been some version of a Christmas Carol, or simply contain a few elements of "It's a Wonderful Life." Regardless, it's tough to go on the information we have. There's a few Twilight Zone episodes (such as "Going My Way", "Ring-A-Ding Girl") with similar elements. Do you have any more information? Lines, actress's hair color etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be the 1955 movie [“Good Morning, Miss Dove”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Morning,_Miss_Dove) starring Jennifer Jones.

From the Wikipedia page:

> *Good Morning, Miss Dove* is a 1955 DeLuxe Color and CinemaScope film that tells the sentimental story of a beloved schoolteacher who reflects back on her life and former students when she is hospitalized.

From the description, there are many short flashbacks that tell stories from Ms. Dove's life.

Similarity to *It's a Wonderful Life*:

> In still another story, there was a "run" on the local bank as frantic depositors waited in line to withdraw their savings. Miss Dove instead deliberately stalled for time as she very leisurely deposited her paycheck just as the teller windows closed at 3:00, angering other depositors. The next morning, the crisis passed as the bank received money from Federal authorities.

Comment: Thank you Doug Small Berries.. I hope this question does not get deleted as I learned something and the mystery was solved. The plot is similar if you read the entire Wikipedia entry - the bank motif and flashbacks but if one reads only the synopsis the match would not make sense.  In fact at first glance it seems more likely to be confused with twilight zone's "The Changing of the Guard".

Comment: @lucasbachmann The question has a positive score and an accepted answer, my understanding is that it cannot be deleted.

Comment: @F1Krazy It would need -3 or -4 and to be closed for 20k users to be able to vote to delete it, not sure if answers factor into user deletion but the answer would mean it shouldn't get roomba'd I believe.

Answer (score -1):

The title is [*It Happened One Christmas*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076213/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl). It was released on Dec 11, 1977 by ABC and starred Marlo Thomas.

> It's Christmas Eve 1944 in the small town of Bedford Falls, New York. A despondent and suicidal Mary Bailey Hatch is praying for guidance on what to do about an incident no fault of her own which threatens her name and the community standing of her longtime family business, the Bailey Building and Loan, which she took over after the passing of her father. [...]
> All the prayers are heard by Joseph, God's gatekeeper of prayers. As there are no other angels available on such a busy day, Joseph assigns Clara Oddbody, angel second class (i.e. she has yet to receive her wings), to Mary's case, which he reluctantly does as Clara has never been assigned a case on her own in the two hundred years she's been in heaven for good reason.